# ubuntu 15.10 login

Tags: 15.10

I was trying to up date to Ubuntu 15.10, while it was downloading the screen went blank. When I restarted the system it went to a login screen and asked for login and password. I don't know what they are. Is there a way to get around this or reset the login name and password ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think the new download was complete, how do I re download it ?

Comment: Redownload it. It's that simple. Seriously, try again.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the login name and password,

- Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).
- From the recovery menu, choose `drop to root shell prompt`

[image]

- Remount your filesystem with write permissions.

  ```
  root@ubuntu:~# mount -o remount,rw /
  ```
- If you don't remember the username, find it by running `cat /etc/passwd`
- To reset the password for the user

  ```
  root@ubuntu:~# passwd your_username
  ```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it is working I can't get in.